# Generating a profile page for a user upon registration

Tags: php, html

I'm currently working on a site that needs to generate a profile page for a user upon registration. I want the page to be in the format www.domain.com/username. Is it possible to do this without creating subdomains?

Comment: Yes. `/username` can be accessed via a `.htaccess` rewrite rule. I'm not good with .htaccess files - sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Create a .htaccess file and use mod_rewrite to route the request.

[Apache - mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

[mod_rewrite cheatsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ - beginners guide to mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this easily using routing rules either in .htaccess file. If you use Codeigniter or zend framework you can do that more easily.

IN Codeigniter:

make a controller: user
make a method: profile
take a parameter: $userName

public function profile($userName){
...............................
}

got to route.php file in application/config/ folder

$route['(a-zA-Z0-9)'] = 'user/profile/$1';

So if you type http://www.domain.com/testuser it will hit to your User controller's profile method and pass the username as parameter to that method as $userName.

That's all...